# How to add dropdown list control using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

How can I add default dropdown in excel sheet using PHPExcel when user add a new row example available for individual cell not for a column or multiple columns.
Example of Excel Template

SL No. | First Name | Middle Name | Last Name | Class | Sec | DOB | Father Name | Selected

Class and Sec require dropdown. Hence when a new student record is added class and sec column should have dropdown. Is it possible through PHPExcel.

If someone could provide a tutorial or something, that would be a real help.

Regards

Comment: http://teclim.ufba.br/aguapura/sistema/lib/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Cell/PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation.html#methodgetShowDropDown

Comment: @dachi I think you missed the line in my post I already mentioned I have gone through examples so naturally I also saw the documentation. Which says how to use and what to use for Dropdown but no where mentioned for the issue I mentioned in my POST. Any way thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called an autoFilter, and there's an entire document in the `/Documentation` folder describing how to set this up - `PHPExcel AutoFilter Reference developer documentation`

At its simplest, you simply define the entire worksheet as an autofilter area using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:I20');
```

(assuming that 20 is the last row in the worksheet)

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension()
);
```

if you want to let PHPExcel calculate the range for you

Comment: IS there any solution in PHPExcel to add List of words like "Male" & "Female" only so user can enter only "Male" or "Female". As I have done in my excel using-

`$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_WHOLE );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_STOP );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
....
$objValidation->setFormula1(1);
$objValidation->setFormula2(2);`

Answer (score 1):

```
        $gender = "Male,female";

          for ($i = 2; $i <= $col_count; $i++) {
                $objValidation = $sheet->getCell('F'.$i)->getDataValidation();
                $objValidation>setType(\PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
                $objValidation->setErrorStyle(\PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
                $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.')
                $objValidation->setFormula1('"'.$gender.'"');

            }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: here, you just call the function. and here I was set cell [ i ], to dropdown, and in dropdown there are two items Male,Female..

Comment: @pankaj thanks for this response! i know this is not what ts asked, but it is what the people are looking for when they get here from google (like i am).