# How to create Dropdown list in excel using php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I need to create a drop down list in excel using php. Actually i need to restrict user's input to given value by me. have a look on the image.
I have generated excel file successfully, but not able to create drop downlist. No help from googling :)please have a look on image. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Depends on how you create an excel sheet with php

Comment: What library are you using ? i would suggest phpexcel : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369758/how-to-add-dropdown-list-control-using-phpexcel. It goes with many examples and documentation

Comment: $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.xls');
        fputcsv($fp, array('Currency Name','Rate/Margin','Selling Price/Margin','Sell Limit','Purchase Price/Margin', 'Purchase Limit'));       
        
        if(is_array($final_added) && count($final_added) > 0)
        {
            foreach($final_added as $key=>$value)
            {
                 
                fputcsv($fp, $value);
            }
        }
here i am generating excel file

Comment: that is csv not excel

Comment: yes but it is genrating .xls file, and its working too.

Comment: Please include that code in the question itself, properly formatted. And as a note, giving a file an `.xls(x)` extension won't magically convert it into an excel-formatted file if it actually contains CSV-formatted data. You only think it works because Excel is capable of opening and handling CSV as well. However, that format does not support dropdown filters and the like, probably that's why you couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"Rate,Margin"');
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using PHPEXCEL API to generate the excel sheet then you can use this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:I20');
```

or this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension()
);
```